# Dockerfile in different folders node configuration

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have project's folder "fruits". And i wanted to dockerize my project with node.

But get the error when i execute "docker-compose up" :

> failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found

My folders is

> - docker
>
>   - node
>
>     - Dockerfile
> - node_modules
> - public
> - src
> - package.json
> - package-lock.json
> - docker-compose.yaml
> - etc

My docker-compose.yaml file is :

```
version: "3"
services:
  node:
    build: docker/node
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:3000
```

My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM node:19-alpine

WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000


CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this is because when you build your image the context is `docker/node` so when you try to `COPY package.json` he isn't found inside `docker/node`

You should be able to fix this by using:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:3000
```

Comment: And if i want to adjust my project "fruits", for example, to folder api(symfony api) and folder ui(react project). I should in Dockerfile make " COPY ui/package*.json ./" . And in docker-compose "volumes: ./ui:/app/ui" ?

Comment: What i wrote above works . Could you give me some links or smt to get better in Docker. You looks pretty good in this?

Comment: I'll suggest you to create a separate container for your ui and your api.
That's mean 2 different dockerfile.
I don't really have resource to share unless official docker documentation, but you can add me on discord, you can find it on my profile if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because that volumes in docker-compose.yml is path relative to docker-compose.yml.

You can try volumes to specify path below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node:
    build: docker/node
    volumes:
      - ../../:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:3000
```